# Prove that $\ker f=\ker g$ implies $f=cg$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, duality-theorems

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$; let $f: V \to \Bbb K$, $g :V \to \Bbb K$ be linear maps, so that $f,g \in V^*$. Prove that if 
$$\ker f=\ker g,$$
then there is some $c \in \Bbb{K}$
such that 
$$f= cg$$
on $V$.

I know that $f= a_1f_1^*+......a_nf_n^*$ where {${f_1^*,....,f_n^*}$} represents a basis of $V^*$.

The same thing for 
$g= b_1f_1^*+......ab_nf_n^*$
and I know that $f(v)=g(v)$
How can I continue?

Comment: Are $f,g$ linear? I ask so because you mention kernel.

Comment: yes $f$ and $g$ are linear

Comment: @GudsonChou: While you're editing: `\ker` gives the correct operator-name spacing. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Got it; thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**: If $f(v) = 0$ for all $v$, there is nothing to prove. Otherwise, pick $v_0$ such that $f(v_{0}) \neq 0$, and put $c = f(v_{0})/g(v_{0})$. (Why is $g(v_{0}) \neq 0$?)

Now look at the kernel of $f - cg$.

Comment: I can't understand

Comment: To show two things are equal in algebra or analysis, it's often easier to set their difference equal to zero. Here, you want to show that if $f$ and $g$ are linear functionals having the same kernel, there exists a $c$ such that $f - cg = 0$. As you note, the first problem is to find $c$ such that $f(v) - cg(v) = 0$ for all $v$. This motivates the suggested strategy. (You can avoid working with bases: By hypothesis, $\ker f = \ker g$; if $f(v) = 0$, what can you say about $g(v)$?) If this doesn't help, can you say specifically what you don't understand? :)

Comment: If I fixed a basis of $\ker f$ (dim $\ker f=n-1$) {$v_1,....,v_{n-1}$}, then $f(v)=f(v_n)$ ?

Comment: Yes, in the sense of taking $v_{n}$ to be an arbitrary vector not in $\ker f$.

Comment: Yes it's ok✌️

Comment: Sorry, but.. May I ask why would $f(v)-cg(v)=0$ for all $v$?

Comment: @KingGhidorah: Can you see that the kernel of $f - cg$ properly contains the common kernel of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: I thought about the question further and now I got it. Thanks.